# what is the difference between these in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, domxpath

I am new to xpath can anyone let me now in detail what is the difference between `/bookstore/*` and `/bookstore` in xpath?

let say this is example input

```
<bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>

<bookstore>

    <book>
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter1</title>
      <price>29.999</price>
    </book>

    <book>
      <title lang="en">Learning XML1</title>
      <price>39.955</price>
    </book>

</bookstore>
```

what will be output in both cases?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output will be almost the same in both cases, i.e. both will select the same elements.

Comment: that is what because i am a little bit confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `/bookstore/*` will select children, `/bookstore` will select the node itself.

For instance, `/bookstore/*` will select *all child elements* under `/bookstore`, so you may end up with a collection of elements. Note that in case this is a more complex expression like `/bookstore/book/*` and there are multiple `/bookstore/book` elements, all children of all matching nodes are selected.

The expression `/bookstore` will select only the element(s) `/bookstore`. Similarily to the above, such select may result in a collection of elements if it's down the path like `/bookstore/book`.

Comment: Not entirely true, `/bookstore` never selects more than 1 node in a well-formed XML document.

Comment: @pakistanimoon: I did, my answer still stands. `/bookstore/*` will select all `book` elements, `/bookstore' will select all `bookstore` elements.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I have assumed that the OP used a simplified expression for the example. Otherwise, your comment about well-formedness is entirely true.

Comment: then in case of /bookstore/* out put wil not contain <bookstore> and </bookstore> ??

Comment: @pakistanimoon I have edited my answer to address it - understanding how the tags are related to the actual content is really crucial. PeterK, I really must insist that you correct your answer; there will never be multiple `/bookstore` elements, however simplified the expression may be.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Ok, that is reasonable -- I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @pakistanimoon: That is correct, using `/*` will select the child nodes only.

Comment: Actually, `/bookstore` can select more than one element - if the input is a tree constructed programmatically rather than by parsing well-formed XML. The data model allows a root node to have more than one element child, which you can create for example using XSLT, or using DOM with a DocumentFragment node as the root node.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree, but in my opinion, "there can be multiple outermost elements" should really come with the explanation you gave - otherwise, it might confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following simple input document:

```
<bookstore>
   <book/>
   <book/>
</bookstore>
```

Now, the expression

```
/bookstore
```

means

> Select an element named `bookstore`, but only if it is the outermost element of the document

There can only be a single outermost element in well-formed XML<sup>1</sup>, so the path expression above will only ever select up to one element node.

```
/bookstore/*
```

means

> Select an element named `bookstore`, but only if it is the outermost element of the document. Then, select all its immediate child elements, regardless of their name.

<sup>1</sup> As Michael Kay points out, except you are constructing an XML tree programmatically. Then, there might be multiple outermost elements.

---

> then in case of /bookstore/* out put wil not contain `<bookstore>` and `</bookstore>`

I can see two ways of reading this question.

**Why both `<element>` and `</element>`?**

Think of `<bookstore>` and `</bookstore>` as **one, single element**. They are the opening and closing *tag* of that element. Once the input document is read into memory, it is stored in a tree-like structure (DOM, for instance) that **does not have opening and closing tags**. And it is this representation you evaluate XPath expressions against.

However, if you output the results of evaluating an XPath expression, then the result tree is *serialized* again, and the tags reappear - which can be confusing.

**Are all elements mentioned in the path selected?**

No, in an expression like

```
/bookstore/book
```

only the `book` element nodes are selected. Only the rightmost item, right after the last *axist step* (things like `/` and `parent::`) is selected.

Comment: have a look on edited question just let me know what will be out put in both cases may be i can understand then easily.

Comment: @pakistanimoon You already have everything you need to understand what the expressions mean. The two documents you'd like to compare have the same structure - so, comparing them is not instructive.